# Bar chart in in ggplot stacked by two columns and dodged for another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, dplyr

I have this data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Month = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
               Trials = c(20,20,20,30,30,30,50,50,50,60,60,60), 
               Subscribers = c(0,0,0,3,5,7,8,13,18,15,25,35),
               Scenario = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
df$Scenario <- as.factor(df$Scenario)
```

I want to create a bar chart that shows, for each month, the sum of trials and subscribers in a stacked form, I also want the different sums for each scenario showed in a dodged form. So for each month there should be 3 bars, one for each scenario. Each bar should be stacked, with two colors, one showing subscribers the other showing trials. As you can see, trials are fixed across scenarios so for each bar, the colored part for trials should be the same, while the colored part for subscribers should change.

This is what I have so far:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(Trials:Subscribers, "keys") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = value, fill = Scenario)) + 
geom_bar(aes(group = keys), stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

which doesn't work.

Is there a way I can achieve this with ggplot? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want a faceted plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
  df %>% 
    pivot_longer(Trials:Subscribers, "keys") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Scenario, y = value, fill = keys)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    facet_grid(cols = vars(Month), labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works! The problem with me is the subscribe part that changes is at the bottom while trials are the upper part of each bar. How can I fix that?